# C Compile Error with Linker

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I'm trying to compile some C code and running into the error:

> Info: Internal Builder is used for build gcc -o Test2.exe
>   "src\Test2.o" 
>   c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot open output file Test2.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

I know that this error is commonly asked about all over the internet, but after reading SEVERAL of the solutions, they seem to be unique to each code sample. I have determined that it is an issue with the linker, but I am not familiar enough with C to know how to narrow it down further than that.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


//initialize function stems
int dotProduct(int vector1[7], int vector2[7]);
void getColumn(int matrix[7][7], int col, int result[7]);
void getRow(int matrix[7][7], int row, int result[7]);
void mulMatrixVec(int matrix[7][7], int vector[7], int result[7]);
void scaleVector(int vector[7], int scale, int result[7]);
void addVector(int vector1[7], int vector2[7], int result[7]);
void mulVector(int vector1[7], int vector2[7], int result[7][7]);
void mulMatrix(int matrix1[7][7], int matrix2[7][7], int result[7][7]);
void subMatrix(int matrix1[7][7], int matrix2[7][7], int result[7][7]);
void scaleMatrix(int matrix[7][7], int scale, int result[7][7]);


int dotProduct(int vector1[7], int vector2[7]){
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        sum += vector1[i]*vector2[i] ;
    }
    return sum;
}

void getColumn(int matrix[7][7], int col, int result[7]){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        result[i] = matrix[i][col];
    }
}

void getRow(int matrix[7][7], int row, int result[7]){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        result[i] = matrix[row][i];
    }
}

void mulMatrixVec(int matrix[7][7], int vector[7], int result[7]){
    int i;
    int row[7];
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        getRow(matrix, i, row);
        result[i] = dotProduct(row, vector);
    }
}

void scaleVector(int vector[7], int scale, int result[7]){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        result[i] = vector[i]*scale;
    }
}

void addVector(int vector1[7], int vector2[7], int result[7]){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        result[i] = vector1[i] + vector2[i];
    }
}

void mulVector(int vector1[7], int vector2[7], int result[7][7]){
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<7; j++){
            result[i][j] = vector1[i]*vector2[j];
        } 
    }
}

void mulMatrix(int matrix1[7][7], int matrix2[7][7], int result[7][7]){
    int i,j;
    int row[7],column[7];
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        getRow(matrix1, i, row);
        for (j = 0; j<7; j++){
            getColumn(matrix2, j, column);
            result[i][j] = dotProduct(row,column);
        }
    }
}

void subMatrix(int matrix1[7][7], int matrix2[7][7], int result[7][7]){
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<7; j++){
            result[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] - matrix2[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void scaleMatrix(int matrix[7][7], int scale, int result[7][7]){
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i<7; i++){
        for (j = 0; j<7; j++){
            result[i][j] = matrix[i][j]*scale;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    int vec1[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int vec2[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int matrix1[7][7] = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8},{3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{4,5,6,7,8,9,0},{5,6,7,8,9,0,1},{6,7,8,9,0,1,2},{7,8,9,0,1,2,3}};

    printf("vector: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d, ", vec1[i]);
    }
    int dotprod = dotProduct(vec1, vec2);
    printf("\nDot Product = %d", dotprod);

    int coltest[7];
    getColumn(matrix1, 0, coltest);
    printf("\ncolumn: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d, ", coltest[i]);
    }

    int rowtest[7];
    getRow(matrix1, 4, rowtest);
    printf("\nrow: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d, ", rowtest[i]);
    }

    int mulMatrixVecTest[7];
    mulMatrixVec(matrix1, vec1, mulMatrixVecTest);
    printf("\nMatrix and Vector Multiplication: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d, ", mulMatrixVecTest[i]);
    }

    int scaleVectorTest[7];
    scaleVector(vec1, 5, scaleVectorTest);
    printf("\nScaled Vector: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d, ", scaleVectorTest[i]);
    }

    int addVectorTest[7];
    addVector(vec1, vec2, addVectorTest);
    printf("\nVector Sum: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d, ", addVectorTest[i]);
    }

    int mulVectorTest[7][7];
    mulVector(vec1,vec2,mulVectorTest);
    printf("\nVector -> Matrix: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            printf("%d, ", mulVectorTest[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    int mulMatrixTest[7][7];
    mulMatrix(matrix1, matrix1, mulMatrixTest);
    printf("\nSquared Matrix");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            printf("%d, ", mulMatrixTest[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    int subMatrixTest[7][7];
    subMatrix(matrix1, matrix1, subMatrixTest);
    printf("\nSubtracted Matrix");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            printf("%d, ", subMatrixTest[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    int scaleMatrixTest[7][7];
    scaleMatrix(matrix1, 5, scaleMatrixTest);
    printf("\nScaled Matrix");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            printf("%d, ", scaleMatrixTest[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
        }

    return 0;
}
```

At one point I commented everything out in an attempt to isolate the cause of the error, but I ran into it even when I was only printing "Vectors" and returning 0 in the main. It says that it couldn't open Test2.exe, so I found where that file existed and attempted to delete it. However, it said that 'Test2.exe cannot be deleted as it is open in Test2.exe' which I found frustratingly amusing (or amusingly frustrating).

Any assistance is appreciated. For reference I am using windows 8.1 and Eclipse with MinGW

Comment: -o Test2.exe <-------------- it's trying to use that as a source file and compile it.

Comment: @B.Nadolson: I don't think that's correct.

Comment: For his purposes, its close enough!  I thought about mentioning object file output and so on, but it just gets to be a long-winded over-technical explanation.

Comment: It sounds as if you have an earlier version of `./Test2.exe` which is in use by some other process, and therefore cannot be overwritten by your build system. I don't know Windows well enough to advise you about how to find that process and shut it down.

Comment: btw this compiles fine under linux exactly as it is.

Comment: The error message says "cannot open output file". Your output file is "Test2.exe". I bet you are still running Test2.exe (possibly in a debugger), so the file cannot be replaced by the linker with a new version.

Comment: @B.Nadolson I turned my computer off and back on and it worked without editing. 

it was a weird bug I can't recreate. Pretty annoying. Like I said, I had figured out test2.exe was runnning somewhere, but I couldnt find where. My computer actually said it was being run by test2.exe which is annoying. Oh well. It works.